# How to Clear Static array in Flex action Script

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am using Flex Action Script.I am facing issue with static array. I have one static array used by two tabs.First time when I login the data is coming fine but if I am going to another tab and coming back to first tab then data from 2nd tab is appended into it and displayed in first.How to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Please add some source code to your question. Now the problem seems to be not understandable, at least for me.

Comment: Indeed. Do you have a static Array object? Post some code.

Answer (score 0):

```
//I'm assuming you have a var like this:
public static var sharedArray:Array;

//Then, assuming you're using a Spark TabBar, make sure you have a "change" listener defined for it, and make sure it includes the following code:
public function onTabChange(event:IndexChangeEvent):void {
    sharedArray = [];
}
```